# how to use context_processor properly in django

Tags: python, django

Here I am trying to redirect to another page if the form is submitted successfully but this code is not working properly .The code saves the form data sends the email , everything is fine but the problem is while redirecting to another page if the form succeed. The error I get is:

> Django Version:    2.0.6 
>   Exception Type:     ValueError 
>   Exception Value:

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

> context_processor.py

```
def volunteer_page2(request):
    volunteer = Volunteer.objects.all().order_by('date')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            message = "{0} with email address {1} has sent you new message \n\n{2}".format(name, email, form.cleaned_data['message'])

            form.save(commit = False)
            try:
                send_mail(name, message, 'appname <settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER>', ['myemail'])
            except:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')

            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Success')
            return redirect('volunteer_page')
        else:
             messages.error(request, "Sorry try again")
    else:
        form = VForm()

    return  {'volunteer': volunteer, 'form':form}
```

> views.py

```
def about_page(request):
    about = About.objects.all().order_by('date')
    banner = Banner.objects.all()

    testimonial = Testimonial.objects.order_by('-pk')[0:2]
    nav = Nav.objects.all()
    footer = Footer.objects.all()

    latest_event2 = Events.objects.order_by('-pk')[0:2]

    context = {
        'about': about,

        'testimonial': testimonial,
        'footer':footer,
        'banner': banner,
        'nav': nav,
        'latest_event2': latest_event2,

    }

    return render(request, 'myapp/about.html', context)
```

> settings.py

```
'myapp.context_processor.volunteer_page2'
```

Answer (score -1):

Django's context processor should always return dictionary. In your code you are returning `HttpResponse` also. This is problem.

Comment: i removed the http response part but also it is not redirecting to the success page but saves the data properly

Comment: Django's context processor is not for this kind of things (For example redirect. BTW, redirect also returns HttpResponse object). Purpose of context processor is to pass variables django template language, which will be rendered per-request.

def my_processor(request):
      return {'name': 'myname', 'surname': 'mysurname'}